# SQLite database not getting updated unless I manually uninstall and then install the new apk

Tags: android, database, sqlite

This is my Database Helper Class :

```
package tabswipe;


import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DB_PATH;
    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final Context context;

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return database;
    }

    public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 93);
        this.context = context;
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
        DB_NAME = databaseName;
        openDataBase();
    }

    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }
        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);


        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;


        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return database;
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //createDataBase();
        openDataBase();

    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS perception_database");
        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

I'm not sure as to what I should put inside the OnCreate and onUpgrade functions so as to facilitate updating of the database without first clearing data and uninstalling.

I am using a prepopulated sqlite database

The database name is umangdb.db

It contains many tables,one of which is perception_database which i am trying to drop and recreate.

I don't mind dropping and recreating all tables as the database is very small.
I was unable to completely understand this database helper class which I sourced from a friend.

Comment: Please consider using `SQLiteAssetHelper` for packaging a database as an asset and deploying it on a site: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 3):

One of the parameters to the constructor of the SQLiteOpenHelper is current version of the DB: [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29). Every time you deploy a new version of the app which requires DB upgrade, you increase the version and thus make it call OnUpgrade method, in which you take care of the changes you made to the database.

Answer (score 0):

In the onUpgrade function, pass a higher version number

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
```

You can drop the tales and recreate the new tables if you dont need to save info from old tables during testing.

```
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tablename);

        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

EDIT:
You can create the following function in the ExternalDbOpenHelper class

```
public void onDelete(Context context){
     context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
}
```

in the onCreate function, call it like this

```
db = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
    db.onDelete(getApplicationContext());
```

Its my understanding you want to destroy and recreate the databse during testing.

Comment: what operation should I perform in the onCreate function ? Please answer in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I recently posted a short tutorial on updating a database with SqlOpenHelper. Maybe it can give you a little guidance as most other tutorials I have seen just drop and recreate the database instead of upgrade with the data intact.

http://android.kuffs.co.uk/2013/12/how-to-handle-database-creation-and.html